# Display PHP_Depend overview pyramid in hudson

Tags: hudson

Does anyone know how it can be displayed the overview pyramid and the jdepend chart generated by PHP_Depend, in hudson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the plugin at http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/JDepend+Plugin for the JDepend chart.

For the php_depend overview image, you can use the plugin at
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/DocLinks+Plugin to link to it.